# Android Google drive API integration unable to add account on debug APK

Tags: android, google-drive-api, drive

i have successfully integrated google drive  API it work fine on **Signed APK**

But when try to run it on debug mode it display add account popup window but unable to signin it display error

```
  ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED,               resolution=PendingIntent{52873b18:
 android.os.BinderProxy@53152a74},
 message=null}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult#SIGN_IN_REQUIRED), error SIGN_IN_REQUIRED means that the client attempted to connect to the service but the user is not signed in.

> The client attempted to connect to the service but the user is not signed in. The client may choose to continue without using the API. Alternately, if [`hasResolution()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult#hasResolution()) returns true the client may call [`startResolutionForResult(Activity, int)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult#startResolutionForResult(android.app.Activity, int)) to prompt the user to sign in. After the sign in activity returns with [`RESULT_OK`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#RESULT_OK) further attempts should succeed.

From this [thread](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/issues/43), try to use `keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\XXXXX.android\debug.keystore -list -v` and not the keystore that you generated since you want the debug mode.

Check these related questions:

- [Android Google+ login doesn't work - statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28882356/android-google-login-doesnt-work-statuscode-sign-in-required)
- [Google Sign In error: Status Code: SIGN_IN_REQUIRED when signing in with Google on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33026544/google-sign-in-error-status-code-sign-in-required-when-signing-in-with-google)

> Make sure SHA-1 signing-certificate fingerprint of your app in google developers console belong to the same key which is used to sign APK you are testing.
>
> By default, when assembling debug build Android Studio use own debug key. You can change it through right-clicking on the app and selecting "Open Module Settings". Go to "Signing" tab and configure the same key you have mentioned in dev console. After that navigate to the "Build Types" tab and select your signing configuration.

Hope this helps!